# Sails 1.0 custom static sources

Tags: sails.js

Prior to Sails 1.0 one could use the `customMiddleware` to add static sources:

```
customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use('/ui', express.static(process.cwd() + '/ui'));
    app.use('/docs', express.static(process.cwd() + '/docs'));
    app.use('/node_modules', express.static(process.cwd() + '/node_modules'));
},
```

But now in Sails 1.0 the `customMiddleware` is deprecated:

```
debug: Warning: use of `customMiddleware` is deprecated in Sails 1.0.
debug: Instead, use an Express 4-compatible middleware (res, res, next) function.
debug: See http://sailsjs.com/docs/upgrading/to-v-1-0#?express-4 for more info.
```

And [the referenced link](http://sailsjs.com/docs/upgrading/to-v-1-0#?express-4) does not say how to replace `app.use('/ui', express.static(process.cwd() + '/ui'));` anywhere.

I've tried so many things, including using serve-static and also trying to set up custom routes, but nothing works.

Is it really possible that in Sails 1.0 we cannot set up custom static sources?